# Look for files not having a given extension

Tags: python, regex

I'v tried the following code.

```
import re

regobj = re.compile(r"^.+\.(oth|xyz)$")

for test in ["text.txt", "other.oth", "abc.xyz"]:
    if regobj.match(test):
        print("Method 1:", test)

regobj = re.compile(r"^.+\.[^txt]$")

for test in ["text.txt", "other.oth", "abc.xyz"]:
    if regobj.match(test):
        print("Method 2:", test)
```

I would like that the 2nd method finds any file not having the extension `txt` but the way I try is not the good one. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill here. Use the [`str.endswith()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
if not str.endswith('.txt'):
```

Your regular expression uses a negative character class, which is a *set* of characters that should not be matched. Anything that is not a `t` or `x` will satisfy that test. You could have explicitly matched `.txt` and used `not` to *exclude* rather than include:

```
regobj = re.compile(r"^.+\.txt$")

if not regobj.match(test):
```

If all you can use is regular expressions, use *negative look-ahead assertions*;

```
 regobj = re.compile(r"^[^.]+\.(?!txt$)[^.]+$")
```

Here `(?!...)` only matches locations where there is *no* literal `txt` following, all the way to the end of the string. The `[^.]+` then matches any number of characters that is not a `.` character until the end of the string.

Comment: You're right but this is to be used in an application where the users can use regexes so I have to find a way to fix that, at least by giving an example. What is really the problem here with the regexes ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ! I will validate your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second regex to,

```
regobj = re.compile(r"^.+\.(?!txt$)[^.]+$")
```

`[^txt]` matches any character not of `t` or `x`. `(?!txt$)` asserts that the dot won't be followed by `txt` . And the `[^.]+` after `\.` asserts that there must be atleast one single char must exists just after to the dot. So this matches the filenames which has  any extensions but not of `.txt`

Comment: Thanks also for the clarification !

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn Pieters mentioned `regex` is overkill, considering there are other more efficient ways:

```
fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(string)
```

Using `splitext` it's simple to isolate the extension.

```
import os

fileDict = ["text.txt", "other.oth", "abc.xyz"]
matchExt = ".txt"

for eachFile in fileDict:
    fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(eachFile)
    if matchExt not in fileExt:
        print("(not %s) %s %s" % (matchExt, fileExt, fileName))
```

You can easily add an `else` statement to match other extensions, which I'll leave up to you.

Comment: You're right but I have already said to Martijn Pieters that my API uses regexes with additional queries. I have decided to add a new query to negate a regex so as to avoid the user to have to use ugly regexes.